# MEAN-Stack - UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found

Tags: mongodb, angular, mean-stack

I want to add User Registration and Login into my Angular2-App. 
I found this [great tutorial from Jason Watmore](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial) . I cloned his repo and checked everything according to his tutorial and also tried the suggestions in his comments.

But still, when i want to access the page at all I get the error below. There seem to be more people with the same problem.

My MongoDB is v3.4.1

Do you have any hints for me? Thanks!

```
UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found

    at middleware (...\server\node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:80:21)
    at ...\server\node_modules\express-unless\index.js:47:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (...\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at ...\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (...\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (...\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (...\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:103:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (...\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
```

Console says:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route is protected from your backend aka your server.js
your server which im assuming is being run on port 3000 is protected unless you provide a token on your indicated method to which your authorizer will extract from usually its the headers.

to over come this i recommend getting a token from aka do a request that will produce one, usually there's a route setup and you can use postman to post data to get a token, once you have a token use postman to send a get request to that same route you couldn't get access to but make sure you add the header authorization or w.e it's looking for the token on. then you'll get access.

Comment: Thanks! I got to register and login via Postman. I also got a JWT Token. 
But i cant access it via Chrome Browser. I will try to change routes and guards etc. so maybe i can get somewhere on my page without beeing asked for a token.

Comment: works fine now. Shame on me, I did not start the App on clientside.